Run tests from different Maven projects
I have a microservice repo and also a separate 'common-tests' repo which contains testNG tests that I would like to re-use across different microservices. (both packaged in Maven).
In CI for my microservice I have been running microservice tests from the /test folder within the same repo. However, I now want to introduce a new test which I have stored in the common-tests repo.
The current tests include an 'install' test which installs Helm charts in a test k8s cluster, an 'upgrade/rollback' test on the deployment and an 'uninstall' test which takes down the Helm deployment. These three tests each have their own test suite xml file and I'm calling them through a 'parent' suite file which invokes them via three  properties.
I want to add a test called 'func-test' which is defined in the common-test repo and has a suite-file in the common-test repo. My problem is that I clone the common-test repo as part of the CI pipeline and I'm not sure how I call my new test, from a different project, right after the 'install' test from my microservice project but before 'uninstall'.
What is the best way to combine these tests/projects?

I have tried just calling the install, then calling the func-test in a different Jenkins step and then calling the upgrade/uninstall afterwards but it was a bit complicated.
I tried adding the common test as a dependency in the ms project's pom and I tried adding 'sources.source' in the config for the execution in the pom of the ms-repo, then in both cases adding the new test to the parent test-suite but I keep encountering 'cannot find class (of common-test) in classPath'.

Why do you have separated tests from your microservice? What kind of tests are those? Can give more details what kind of project that is? Spring Boot / Quarkus?

I don't really know what you are doing here, but it does read like you're trying to roll your own too much. Maven has a feature called a test jar, which is exactly intended to package tests in a jar which can then be put on the test path of multiple projects. Is that not an option? https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/examples/create-test-jar.html
